# Is it possible to alter accordian properties after init has run in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I have an accordian that I need to change some properties depending on if the user has updated parts of a form. Is it possible to touch that accordions properties after the init method has run. So for example, change the header property on a button click, or something to that extent?

Here is the accordian code:

```
function _initAccordian() {

//init accordian, and handels preserving the state of the accordian for the user UI
var $accordian = $("#agencySettingsAccordian"),
    activeIndex;

$accordian.accordion({
    animate: 200,
    header: "h3", //makes user not allowed to open on page load
    collapsable: true,
    active: true,
    heightStyle: "content",
    create: function (event, ui) {
        //get index in cookie on accordion create event
        if ($.cookie('accordian_saved_index') != null) {
            activeIndex = parseInt($.cookie('accordian_saved_index'));
        }
        console.log(activeIndex);
    },
    activate: function (event, ui) {
        //set cookie for current index on change event
        $.cookie('accordian_saved_index', null);
        $.cookie('accordian_saved_index', $accordian.accordion("option", "active"));
        console.log($.cookie('accordian_saved_index'));
    },
    active: parseInt($.cookie('accordian_saved_index')) || null 
});


}
```

How can I change the "header" property for example on a button click event?

Comment: Yep, it's possible. What have you tried and where'd you get stuck?

Comment: Well, I just came across a new idea of what I wanted to do.I am using the disable and enable methods. I am pretty much disabling it until they select a agency id in a form, then it loads the content, and they can use it.

Comment: My current code is just a regular accordian init. And then trying to change the header property later on another event.

Comment: I worked it out another way, but not by changing the property. I am just calling those methods "enable, disable".